# In python, how can i Prepending a timestamp to each line of output coming from serial?

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

I want to log the timestamp for output data coming from serial hardware. I can just prepend timestamp for first instances coming from serial but not able to log for every line. 
For example: 
right now, I'm able to log timestamp as below:

---

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : $GV0040

?GB

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : $GB00402eef

$GB00403eef

?GB

$GB00402eef

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : *AQ0401

---

But I want timestamp on everyline. like below:

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : $GV0040

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : ?GB

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : $GB00402eef

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : ?GB

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : $GB00402eef

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : ?GB

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : $GB00402eef

[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : *AQ0401

what is the way to log output data timestamp on every line in python?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if each line begins with a timecode in the right format. If it doesn't, add it based on the previous timecode.

If `lines` is a generator or something containing, each line from serial, you could do something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime

last_timecode = datetime.now()
time_format = '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(' :')
    if len(parts) > 1:
        try:
            datetime.strptime(parts[0], time_format)
            last_timecode = parts[0]
            print(line)
        except ValueError:
            print(f'{last_timecode} : {line}')
    else:
        print(f'{last_timecode} : {line}')
```

---

Breaking this down, we take each line, and try to split it at `' :'`. The original line could have been any of these types:

1. `?GB` becomes `['?GB']` after splitting
2. `?GB : other` becomes `['?GB', ' other']` after splitting
3. `[2019-12-20 16:30:28] : *AQ0401` becomes `['[2019-12-20 16:30:28]', '*AQ0401']` after splitting

If there is more than one part and the first part doesn't match the date format or there is only one part, prepend the line with the correct date.

Otherwise, there is more than one part, so we check if the first one matches the correct date format. If it does, just print the same line (no changes), and save the date, to be used in future lines that don't have one.